# How to override QML item

Tags: qt, qml

I have a 'base' component which controls the aspect ratio of the item 'childItem':

```
//AspectRatio.qml

import QtQuick 2.12

Rectangle
{
  property real targetAspectRatio: 16 / 9

  color: "black"
  anchors.fill: parent

  onWidthChanged:
  {
    var _ratio = parent.width / parent.height
    var _width = 0

    if(_ratio > targetAspectRatio) //Too wide
    {
      _width = parent.height * targetAspectRatio
    }
    else
    {
      _width = parent.width
    }

    childItem.width = _width
  }

  onHeightChanged:
  {
    var _ratio = parent.width / parent.height
    var _height = 0

    if(_ratio > targetAspectRatio) //Too wide
    {
      _height = parent.height
    }
    else
    {
      _height = parent.width / targetAspectRatio
    }

    childItem.height = _height
  }

  Item
  {
    id: childItem
    anchors.centerIn: parent
  }
}
```

I want to use AspectRatio.qml as a generic component and override 'childItem', depending on the context the component is used. How can 'childItem' be overridden, like this?

```
//child.qml

AspectRatio
{
  childItem : Rectangle
  {
    color: "red"
  }
}
```

This mechanism is also used in standard qml components, like [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#background-prop). But it's unclear to me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple solutions for your problem.

You could create a childItem property and manually put it in the [children](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#children-prop) property of `Item` like so:

```
// AspectRatio.qml
Rectangle {
  property real targetAspectRatio: 16 / 9

  property Item childItem
  children: [childItem]

  color: "black"
  anchors.fill: parent

  onWidthChanged: // ...

  onHeightChanged: // ...
}
```

```
// Usage
AspectRatio {
    childItem : Rectangle {
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could do it the other way and bind the childItem to the children and not have an explicit setter and your property just being a "view" into `children`:

```
readonly property Item childItem: children[0]
```

```
// Usage
AspectRatio {
    Rectangle { /* ... */  }
}
```

To be able to use both syntax you could use a default property, overriding the Item's children default property:

```
default property Item childItem
children: [childItem]
```

```
// Usage
AspectRatio {
    Rectangle { /* ... */  }
}
// OR
AspectRatio {
    childItem: Rectangle { /* ... */  }
}
```

I'd say this one is my preferred solution.

---

You didn't ask but I would replace your imperative code in onWidth/heightChanged by declarative bindings (and move the anchors outside):

```
Rectangle {
    id: root
    property real targetAspectRatio: 16 / 9
    default property Item childItem
    children: [childItem]
    color: "black"
    Binding {
        target: root.childItem
        property: "width"
        value: Math.min(root.height * root.targetAspectRatio, root.width)
    }
    Binding {
        target: root.childItem
        property: "height"
        value: Math.min(root.width / root.targetAspectRatio, root.height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't "override" an item, but you can create a property that points to the child list of an item. This is how things like the `background` property that you mentioned on controls work. By assigning to this property, you're essentially inserting an object as a child of whatever the containing Item is.

```
//AspectRatio.qml
Rectangle
{
    property alias childItem: childContainer.data

    Item 
    {
        id: childContainer
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}

//child.qml
AspectRatio
{
    childItem : Rectangle
    {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

Comment: `childItem` wouldn't be an Item property there, the `background` property of controls doesn't work like that. OP also wouldn't be able to do `childItem.height = _height` with your solution.

Comment: You might be right about the background property, but where does the OP say they want to do `childItem.height`?

Comment: In their code snippet.

Comment: Ah, I see that now in the base component. This will still work as long as the child Rectangle does something like `anchors.fill: parent`. But did you have a different solution in mind?

Comment: As an aside @GrecKo, I recognize you from some of your work, and I always dread it when you comment on my posts because it almost always means I missed something. : )

Comment: Hehe I guess that's a compliment here on SO, sorry if I come off as too pedantic sometimes (: